# Convert JSON into new JSON with other structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON representing a tree diagram and want to convert this to a JSON with a new structure that it can be visualized with treant.js.

It should be working with different number of nodes. Each node/children can have 0 or 2 children. That's actually my main problem how to iterate over the input JSON to get all children and sub-children without having a loop for each child.

Also the title of a parent-node is represented only in it's childs, but I need it in the parent itself.

input:

```
treeModel = {
"TreeModel": {
    "AlgorithmName": "CART",
    "Child": [{
        "RecordCount": 47,
        "Score": "1", //should be the name
        "ScoreDistribution": [
            [24, 23], //should be the description as string
            [0.5106382978723404, 0.4893617021276596]
        ],
        "TreeNodePredicate": {
            "FieldPredID": 0,
            "FieldPredName": "Attribute1", //should be the title from parent
            "FieldValue": 0,
            "Operator": "EQUAL",
            "PredicateType": "SimplePredicate"
        }
    }, {
        "RecordCount": 214,
        "Score": "0", //should be the name
        "ScoreDistribution": [
            [2, 212], //should be the description as string
            [0.009345794392523364, 0.9906542056074767]
        ],
        "TreeNodePredicate": {
            "FieldPredID": 0,
            "FieldPredName": "Attribute1", //should be the title from parent
            "FieldValue": 1,
            "Operator": "EQUAL",
            "PredicateType": "SimplePredicate"
        }
    }],
    "RecordCount": 261,
    "Score": "0", //should be the name
    "ScoreDistribution": [
        [26, 235], //should be the description as string
        [0.09961685823754787, 0.9003831417624522]
    ],
    "TreeNodePredicate": {
        "PredicateType": "TruePredicate"
    }
}
}
```

output:

```
chart_config = {
chart: {
    container: "#tree-simple"
},

nodeStructure: {
    text: { 
        name: "0" , //Score
        title: "Attribute1", //FieldPredName from Child
        desc: "26, 235", //ScoreDistribution as String
    },
    children: [
        {
            text: { 
                name: "1" , //Score
                title: "", //FieldPredName from Child(empty as no childs)
                desc: "24, 23", //ScoreDistribution as String
            }
        },
        {
            text: { 
                name: "0" , //Score
                title: "", //FieldPredName from Child(empty as no childs
                desc: "2, 212", //ScoreDistribution as String
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

Comment: This is not code-writing service, try solving your problem yourself, come back when you get stuck.

Comment: Pass it to a constructor that reassigns the values. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive and iterative approach for converting.

```js
function convert(source) {
    var target = {
            text: {
                name: source.Score,
                title: source.Child && source.Child[0] && source.Child[0].TreeNodePredicate && source.Child[0].TreeNodePredicate.FieldPredName || '',
                desc: source.ScoreDistribution[0].join(', ')
            }
        };

    if (Array.isArray(source.Child)) {
        target.children = source.Child.map(convert);
    }
    return target;
}

var treeModel = { TreeModel: { AlgorithmName: "CART", Child: [{ RecordCount: 47, Score: "1", ScoreDistribution: [[24, 23], [0.5106382978723404, 0.4893617021276596]], TreeNodePredicate: { FieldPredID: 0, FieldPredName: "Attribute1", FieldValue: 0, Operator: "EQUAL", PredicateType: "SimplePredicate" } }, { RecordCount: 214, Score: "0", ScoreDistribution: [[2, 212], [0.009345794392523364, 0.9906542056074767]], TreeNodePredicate: { FieldPredID: 0, FieldPredName: "Attribute1", FieldValue: 1, Operator: "EQUAL", PredicateType: "SimplePredicate" } }], RecordCount: 261, Score: "0", ScoreDistribution: [[26, 235], [0.09961685823754787, 0.9003831417624522]], TreeNodePredicate: { PredicateType: "TruePredicate" } } },
    chart_config = { chart: { container: "#tree-simple" }, nodeStructure: convert(treeModel.TreeModel) };

console.log(chart_config);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```